# NumericArray in DICOM Implementation of Version 12.1

Tags: import, numeric-array

The 12.1 reimplementation of import for DICOM data seems to bring in the data from a single slice as a `NumericArray`, In the past, the data would be returned as a list of lists of numbers `{{1,1,1,...},{2,2,2,,,},...}`.

This change to an Experimental feature has broken a bit of really old code for me. I am wondering if there is a way to redefine the data import in a way that restores the behavior i have utilized in the past.

For example, in the past, to view non-planar image, i could just import the data from a list of files:

`UseData=(Import[#,"Data"]&)/@UseFNList;`

Then select the data to display in the list indices:

`Print[ArrayPlot[UseData[[All,255,1;;255]]]];`

The issue is from accessing the array. The command `UseData[[All,255,1;;255]]` results in an error:

`Part::Cannot take positions 10 through 100 in {NumericArray[Type: UnsignedInteger, Length: 512],NumericArray[Type: UnsignedInteger, Length: 512],NumericArray[Type: UnsignedInteger, Length: 512],...}`

It's not so bad, but now the import operation requires the additional step of applying `Normal` to the typed array:

`UseData=(Normal[Import[#,"Data"]]&)/@UseFNList;`

I can do a search and replace through all the libraries, but i am wondering if there is a smarter way to fix my issue.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Mark

Comment: `ArrayPlot` usually works fine with `NumericArray`, it's surprising that it doesn't work here.

Comment: @MassDefect Thanks! The issue isn't from the use of ArrayPlot, it's from trying to view the array edge-on. I will clean up the question to make that more clear.

Answer (score 3):

If what you need is specifically to get "Data" in packed array ("list of numbers") instead of NumericArray, then I do not see any better solution than `Normal`izing. There is no `Import` element that would give exactly what you want.

As for

> to view non-planar image, i could just import the data (...)

Perhaps `Import[xxx.dcm, "Image"]`, which gives the `Image` object directly, would be a better choice here.

Comment: Thanks @raflac! That would import as a list of images.